# jquery ui-dialog form submiting not work

Tags: jquery, forms, user-interface, submit

```
var currentForm;
$("#confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "First we must ask you!",
    resizable: false,
    width:500,
    height:190,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Submit for God sake!': function() {
            currentForm.submit();
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }       
});
$('.clientForm').submit(function(e){
    currentForm = $(this);
    $('#confirm').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Hello.

I have an form which must submit only after confirmation. To execute this i use ui-dialog method. Problem is that the form don't want submit after ui-dialog appears and visitor must click to confirmation button.

As i look at the code, everething seems to be correct.

**Here the link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khkwzsf0/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not posting because of this line `return false;` in form submit event. This is causing the form to not post.

```
$('.clientForm').submit(function(e){
        currentForm = $(this);
        $('#confirm').dialog('open');
        return false; // this line will always stop your form from posting
    });
```

Give the submit button id and write its click event:

```
 <button id="go" type="submit">Go there</button>
```

jquery event:

```
$('#go').click(function(e){
        currentForm = $(this).closest("form");
        $('#confirm').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

### [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/khkwzsf0/2/)

Another alternate is to make button type `button` instead of `submit` this will not cause your form to be submitted on click:

```
<button id="go" type="button">Go there</button>
```

and jquery:

```
$('#go').click(function(e){
        currentForm = $(this).closest("form");
        $('#confirm').dialog('open'); // no need to return false as button type is not submit
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/khkwzsf0/3/)

Comment: Thank for answer. So You want to say in this case the solution is not exist? After all, if i remove return false ui-dialog appears, but form not pause own submit. Is any way to pasue, not stop submit?

Comment: see my updated answer, you have to give button id write it's click event to stop submitting.

Comment: Thanks. Now form was really submited.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except `$('.clientForm').submit(function(e){`.

Replace `$('.clientForm').submit(function(e){` with `$('.clientForm').click(function(e){`. This should work.